# Exception when adding interface type that holds already registered types

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

Frontend developers are requesting an interface that holds all the types that are currently validatable in our system.

I have created the following interface `IValidatable`

```
public interface IValidatable
{
    public AddressInput AddressInput { get; set; }
    // Here are potentially more input types
}
```

I have added the interface type to the schema

```
.AddInterfaceType<IValidatable>();
```

When loading the schema from Banana Cake Pop I get the following exception

```
The name `AddressInput` was already registered by another type. (HotChocolate.Types.InputObjectType<AddressInput>)
```

How can I include an interface type to the schema that holds already registered types?

---

Why are frontend developers requesting a type that holds all validatable types?

Think of the `nameof()` expression in C#. They want this same feature in TypeScript, so that if we backend developers change a property name on a type, this should be reflected in the schema and give a compile-time error when building the frontend application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly the answer to your specific question, but if the problem is only to validate schema and be in sync with the server for meta data, why not using something similar like: https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen.
There are also other tooling's which can generate GraphQL clients or only parts of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).